# Bootstrap pagination-sm with DataTables

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I would like to have my Datatables pagination styled like the Bootstrap pagination.

So, at the moment it looks like this:

[image: Actual look]

If I add

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

it looks like this:

[image: Look with dataTables.bootstrap.min.js]

And I want it to look like this:

[image: Wanted look]

I don't know why the additional js-file causes this distance between the buttons.

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: In order to get a more helpful response, please include the code in your example attempt above. The screenshots are helpful to visualize what you expect vs what you see but the attempted code should always be included as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code link? Hope it will work for you. we have added `jQuery`, `jquery.dataTable.js`, and `jquery.dataTables.min.css` as per Data table documentation (https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html).

We have applied style as per your required design and removed margin from pagination button like following.

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate a.paginate_button {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/360sefnL/2/

Comment: We did the styling of pagination( jsfiddle link) based on screenshots you provided, we can help you if you add your complete code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You might be forget to include the CSS library files. can you please check and add below CSS link into your code.

The following CSS library files are loaded for use in this example to provide the styling of the table:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css

And please follow the given link and check the CSS tab information.

https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4

Comment: css was included